# Python: How to enumerate over a list of lists and use the length of that list to find values

Tags: python

I'm building a slot machine simulator in Python. I have setup the reels as follows:

```
Reels = [[10,9,4,5,7,4,9,2,6,7,3,4,9,3,4,9,6,5,4,11,8,9,11,2,4,1,9,10,4,9,10,6,4,9,1,5,4,9,1,10,3,8,6,4,9,1,8],
            [4,3,5,4,3,5,2,8,4,1,8,10,1,2,9,8,11,2,8,5,6,11,3,4,2,8,4,7,6,10,8,7,9,4,1,6,8,4,2,9,8,3,5,4,10,8],
            [1,9,4,2,5,1,6,9,2,5,9,2,10,9,4,8,9,11,2,5,8,9,10,4,1,10,9,2,10,5,9,7,5,6,8,9,7,3,10,6,2,9,5,8,3,1,10,3],
            [8,10,3,8,7,3,9,8,10,11,3,10,9,6,8,10,11,6,5,3,8,1,4,9,5,8,1,4,3,8,1,5,9,10,8,3,9,4,3,8,9,4,6,11,3,8,9,7,10,11],
            [4,11,1,6,3,9,5,10,9,5,8,11,10,3,1,4,10,3,9,4,7,3,9,10,4,3,1,5,10,6,5,8,4,6,9,1,5,10,8,9,5,4,6,8,9,4,8,5,7,9]]
```

Now I need to iterate through them from 1 through 5 and build a 3X5 matrix. I want to start by producing a random number that determines where on that reel to stop. That value will be the middle value on that reel. Then, I need to add the top and bottom values (but have to account for the middle number potentially being at the beginning or end of the reel strip. I'm getting the error "list index out of range" on the `if StopValue == Reels[i][len(Reels[i])]:` line:

```
def spin():
    SpinValues = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]

    for i, object in enumerate(Reels):
        length = len(Reels[i])
        StopValue = random.randint(0,length)
        SpinValues[i][1] = Reels[i][StopValue]
        if StopValue == 0:
            SpinValues[i][0] = Reels[i][len(Reels[i])]
        else:
            SpinValues[i][0] = Reels[i][StopValue - 1]
        if StopValue == Reels[i][len(Reels[i])]:
            SpinValues[i][2] = Reels[i][0]
        else:
            SpinValues[i][2] = Reels[i][StopValue +1]
    print(SpinValues)

spin()
```

Initially I thought I could do this with just "for i in reels," but I read a post here suggesting to use the "for index, object in enumerate(Reels)" method.

Comment: Have you tried negative indexing? Say you have a list `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and you try `my_list[-1]` it will return `5`. Maybe you can implement logic such that it can use this to loop to the other side of your list?

Comment: You could instead use a list of [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.deque), which have a [`rotate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.deque.rotate) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len(Reels[i])` is not a valid index for `Reels[i]`.  The last valid index is `len(Reels[i]) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

To refer to the last item in a list called `my_list`, you must use

```
my_list[-1]
```

or

```
my_list[len(my_list)-1]
```

and not:

```
my_list[len(my_list)]
```

The reason is that in Python, all indexing starts from `0`, and not from `1`